# How does spark-submit.sh work with different modes and different cluster managers?

Tags: apache-spark, cluster-computing

In Apache Spark,  how does spark-submit.sh work with different modes and different cluster managers? Specifically:

In local deployment mode,

- does spark-submit.sh skip calling any cluster manager?
- Is it correct that there is no need to install a cluster manager on the local machine?

In client or cluster deployment mode,

- Does spark-submit.sh work with different cluster managers (Spark standalone, YARN, Mesos, Kubernetes)? Do different cluster managers have different interfaces, and spark-submit.sh has to invoke them in different ways?
- Does spark-submit.sh appear to programmers the same interface except `--master`? option `--master` of spark-submit.sh is used to specify a cluster manager.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To make things clear, there is absolutely no need to specify any cluster manager while running spark on any mode (`client` or `cluster` or whether you run spark in `local` mode). The cluster manager is only there to make resource allocation easier and independent, but it is always your choice to use one or not.

The `spark-submit` command doesn't need a cluster manager present to run.

The different ways in which you can use the command are:

1) `local` mode:

```
./bin/spark-submit \
  --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi \
  --master local[8] \
  /path/to/examples.jar \
  100
```

2) `client` mode without a resource manager (also known as [spark standalone mode](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-standalone.html)):

```
./bin/spark-submit \
  --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi \
  --master spark://207.184.161.138:7077 \
  --executor-memory 20G \
  --total-executor-cores 100 \
  /path/to/examples.jar \
  1000
```

3) `cluster` mode with spark standalone mode:

```
./bin/spark-submit \
  --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi \
  --master spark://207.184.161.138:7077 \
  --deploy-mode cluster \
  --supervise \
  --executor-memory 20G \
  --total-executor-cores 100 \
  /path/to/examples.jar \
  1000
```

4) Client/Cluster mode with a resource manager:

```
./bin/spark-submit \
  --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi \
  --master yarn \
  --deploy-mode cluster \  # can be client for client mode
  --executor-memory 20G \
  --num-executors 50 \
  /path/to/examples.jar \
  1000
```

As you can see above, the spark-submit.sh will behave in the same way whether there is a cluster manager or not. Also, if you want to use a resource manager like yarn, mesos, the behaviour of spark-submit will remain the same. 
You can read more about `spark-submit` [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html).