# Does spark-submit parameters work in local mode?

Tags: apache-spark

When I run `spark-submit --master local[10] --num-executors 8 --executor-cores 5 --executor-memory 5g foo.jar`,which means I am running an application in local mode,will `--num-executors 8 --executor-cores 5 --executor-memory` work together with `local[10]`? If not,which parameters will decide the resources allocation?

In other words,does `--num-executors 8 --executor-cores 5 --executor-memory 5g` only works on yarn?In local mode,only `local[K]` works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the spark-submit parameters `num-executors`, `executor-cores`, `executor-memory` won't work in local mode because these parameters are to be used when you deploy your spark job on a cluster and not a single machine, these will only work in case you run your job in `client` or `cluster` mode.

Please refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60703518/6874807) for more information on different ways to submit a spark application.